# System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be empty with a literal string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, exception, razor-2

Cannot figure this one out.

I have the following markup in a view (MVC 4, Razor 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var PageApiCtor = {
    TempProfilePicUrl: '@Url.Action("TempPic", "Member")',
    CropUrl: '@Url.Action("CropAndSave", "Member")',
    DeletePicUrl: '@Url.Action("DeletePic", "Member")',
    NoPicUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Content/images/no-pic.gif")',
    LastProfileRef: undefined
};
```

The error is as follows:

[image]

Clearly, there is a value being supplied.

So, I then hard-coded the string and got the same error on a different line:
[image]

So, I then added console output statements. The exception then occurred immediately after the JS section:
[image]

These controllers/actions do exist so I am baffled by this. I have seen stuff like this before where the Razor parser throws an unrelated error but never this strange:

Any ideas?

I am now going to systematically remove page content so I can isolate the issue, as I have not clue at this point, other than the exceptions thrown are clearly not occurring on the lines indicated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get the same error if you hard code the no-pic.gif link? (just to test)

Comment: Yes, thanks. No change. See my update

Comment: Interesting. I manually typed out that same script into a fresh MVC4 app and it runs without problem. I think even though it is pointing you to there.. your problem is elsewhere? Initializing a javascript object (really from no Model or anything) shouldn't cause a .net exception. Can you log something to browser console before that object, and then log the object after? does the console show the object before you get that exception?

Answer (score 0):

There was a `@Url.Content()` call way down the page, not even close to the exception break point, that was passing in an empty string. Not null, an empty string.That was the problem